# Make Apache server only to be avaliable for personal use?

Tags: apache, xampp

I'm afraid if I have Apache active that someone can hack into my computer so everytime I had Apache active I went offline (I also installed XAMPP on USB stick because of that fear).

How can I make Apache server to be avaliable only to me for PHP testing purposes?
Going offline and online became exhausting.

Comment: If its running locally just access it via 127.0.0.1 and block external access. Similar thread http://serverfault.com/questions/276963/make-apache-only-accessible-via-127-0-0-1-is-this-possible